# Mr Schudy tells me I am in a group when I am not

Tags: tower-of-fantasy

I joined a team for an activity, and once completed we all left. However now my quest NPC, Mr Schudy, tells me that I am in a group and cannot progress my quest.

[image: Mr Schudy telling me that I am already in a group and must quit]

I cannot find a way to leave the group. When you are in a group players are listed in a panel on the right hand side of the UI.

I have quit the game and re-launched only to experience the same issue.

How can I leave my group? Or are there known issues with groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a very well hidden work around to this issue.

**PC**, Press <kbd>T</kbd> and select the flag icon, which appears on the right, to reach the lobby

**Mobile**, Tap the quest you're tracking on the right to make the flag slide out, and tap to enter the lobby

[image: Your team tab of the multiplayer lobby]

Now I can progress my quest.

[image: Mr Schudy offering my character the quest]